# intranet chat application using java

Tags: java, chat, intranet

Any help would be great please..!

1. How to build an intranet chat application using java which includes transform of files like gtalk?
2. where to start the process?
3. what all the sw requirements?

Answer (score 1):

The [Eclipse Communication Framework](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/) includes [several use cases based upon real-time shared editing](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/NewAndNoteworthy_2.0.0M4b.html) over XMPP/Google Talk and Skype

And ECF is the base for a [twitter client](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/NewAndNoteworthy.html) (as an example of what you can do with that framework)

[image]

Comment: Thanks much vonc but what is twitter client?

Comment: @Bhuvana http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter "Twitter has been described as akin to a Web-based Internet Relay Chat (IRC) client": that is why I mentioned it: as an example of a particular type of chat. In Java. based on ECF.

Comment: Any idea if ecf needs an osgi container ?

Answer (score 1):

you must have learned networking in java (java.net.*)
be sure of what king d of architecture you want to use

- client/server
- p2p
- xmpp

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deploy one, you can use [Jabber](http://www.jabber.com/) with one of [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_(software)) [Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jclaim/) Clients out there.

If you need to write your own server and/or client, you can start with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177514/good-xmpp-java-libraries-for-server-side) and use an existing XMPP (IM protocol) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Why build one when good open source solutions based on open standards are available.

Take a look at running an [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) XMPP (Jabber) server.

Theres a variety of clients available the best being:

- [Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp)
- [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/)

I beleive that a [flash client](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) is also available.

Comment: Thanks pjp ,i want to develop chat application for my office purpose.so i planned to do myself.