# GAE messaging service

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jms, rmi

Let's say I want my corporate server to communicate with Google App Engine and vice versa. I know that GAE does not support JMS,RMI etc. What is the best alternative for this kind of communication?   Use task queue? (I think HTTP `get()` is not suitable for this kind of communication).

Both my corporate server and GAE application use Spring framework.

Answer (score 2):

XMPP is a powerful and flexible messaging protocol, and [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html) shows how to do the GAE side of it in both Java and Python.  For XMPP implementations (in Java and others) outside of GAE, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177514/good-xmpp-java-libraries-for-server-side).

For accessing from GAE a lot of bulky secure data that lives behind your corporate firewall, Google recommends implementing the [Secure Data Connector](http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/docs/1.0/tutorials/appengine.html) (I'm pointing specifically to the URL of the Java tutorial for SDC with GAE).

Comment: and... it's all removed and the links are broken.

Answer (score 1):

Use any of a number of HTTP based RPC protocols: REST, JSONRPC, SOAP, etc.

You say "I think http get() is not suitable for this kind of communication" - why not?

Comment: @Nick, slow. let say i need very frequent calls in 1 seconds, would be better to use jms compared to http get right?

Comment: No. There's nothing slow about RPCs over HTTP. They're extremely optimized, in fact, since users are very time sensitive and fetch pages over HTTP all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [task queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/). It does the same that JMS does.

You can also use [Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) or any other similar service.

What you going to do is basically configure a WebServlet and implement the HttpServlet doPost method. In specific for Google Cloud Pub/Subm you should use the url pattern `/_ah/push-handlers`

Here the example from the docs of AppEngine for the receiver:

```
// The Enqueue servlet should be mapped to the "/enqueue" URL.
// With @WebServlet annotation the webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml is no longer required.
@WebServlet(
    name = "TaskEnque",
    description = "taskqueue: Enqueue a job with a key",
    urlPatterns = "/taskqueues/enqueue"
)
public class Enqueue extends HttpServlet {

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String key = request.getParameter("key");

    // Add the task to the default queue.
    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
    queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/worker").param("key", key));

    response.sendRedirect("/");
  }
}
```