# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets

I developing a web application using GWT where i am trying to upload a file . My servlet is working fine.

but when i use DiskFileItemFactory() it gives me error.

if some one can correct my code or tell what is missing in  code.

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws ServletException, IOException { 

         response.setContentType("text/plain"); 
        FileItem uploadItem = getFileItem(request); 
        if (uploadItem == null) { 
          response.getWriter().write("NO-SCRIPT-DATA"); 
          return; 
        } 
        byte[] fileContents = uploadItem.get(); 
        //TODO: add code to process file contents here. We will just print 

                    response.getWriter().write(new String(fileContents)); 
}

private FileItem getFileItem(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); 
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory); 
    try { 
      List items = upload.parseRequest(request); 
      Iterator it = items.iterator(); 
      while (it.hasNext()) { 
        FileItem item = (FileItem) it.next(); 
        if (!item.isFormField() 
            && "uploadForm".equals(item.getFieldName())) { 
          return item; 
        } 
      } 
    } catch (FileUploadException e) { 
      return null; 
    } 
    return null;
}
```

ERROR

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.<clinit>(DiskFileItem.java:109)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:361)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
at com.server.FileUpload.getFileItem(FileUpload.java:101)
at com.server.FileUpload.doPost(FileUpload.java:48)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
```

Edited: Working Code

```
    try {
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            response.setContentType("text/plain"); 


            FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = iterator.next();

                InputStream stream = item.openStream();

                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    log.warning("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName()  + " " +item);



                } else{
                    log.warning("Got an uploaded file: " + item.getFieldName() +
                              ", name = " + item.getName());
                    int len;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    while ((len = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {

                      response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, len);

                    }

                }

            }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use RMI in GAE - if you want something similar, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533415/gae-messaging-service).

But from your code it doesn't seem you need to use RMI at all - why are you using it? Ain't you just going to process and store it somewhere?

If you are going to store large files (up to 32MB), use the [Blobstore API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/).

If you know you'll only have files <1MB, you can store them using JDO/JPA and a normal [Entity](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html)  that contains a [Blob](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Blob.html) - this option will also allow you to easily pre-process the data.

Comment: yes i just want to process it and store it and also file size can be more then 1 MB ,type of file can be txt,doc and pdf. Please tell what code should i write.

Comment: @NewCodeLearner please check the updated answer and [this link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html).

Comment: Plz check the edited part in question.
can you explain why this code is working.