# Different behaviour in Eclipse with Google Eclipse Plugin than Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I have a Google App Engine project created in Eclipse with the Google Eclipse Plugin.

When I run some of its services locally with the GAE SDK they work fine, but when I deploy the app on "the real" Google App Engine and try to access any of these services, chrome throws the following error:

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

On the other hand, I also get [**THIS**](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1Lg8GzZGJyLU2VMeXc0ckZfekE/edit) error locally when trying to call an upload method.

All of this is someone else's project and it's meant to work, besides I don't think the error is related to the code, hence, I don't think it's worth it posting it here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501527/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-rmi-server-uid-is-a-restricted-class

Comment: thx @matcheek, don't know how I couldn't find that before...