# Implementing a IM platform in Java

Tags: java, rmi

If creating an IM platform in Java, which would be a better way to implement communications between the clients and server?
I was thinking either RMI or just a socket connection...

Advice please,

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use straight socket connection, using a well known protocol such as [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/). You can use a library (like [smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)) to avoid implementing the whole protocol yourself.

The main advantage of XMPP over RMI or your self-made protocol is that is a well established protocol used for exactly that purpose: IM.

Some chat services already using XMPP include Google Chat (GTALK) and Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I already did this using [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) API, using XMPP protocol.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177514/good-xmpp-java-libraries-for-server-side

Answer (score 0):

[CometD](http://cometd.org/) has been specifically designed for use cases such as Chatrooms. Differently from other protocols, it works over HTTP port 80, which means (nearly) no hassles with Firewalls.

Listen to [a recent podcast with Greg Wilkins](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4571.html) about the project, which goes into some details of issues with implementing Chatrooms and how it gets handled by CometD.

I believe there is a Java client for CometD if you need to have client on both sides of conversation (normally frontend is JavaScript).