# Android : Client server programming

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Am new to GCM in android. From various videos resources, now i have some knowledge on client side connections in GCM. but am lack in server side programming.

I have desktop at my home, i just want to make that as a server, sending some data across my mobile and desktop.

I don't know how to make my desktop as a server, how to connect to my desktop IP from android, how to send data to GCM server from desktop server, which language would be best on server side.

Guidance is much appreciated.

Regards,
Aswin.

Answer (score 0):

The code below so this makes a nice basic working example of how to use GCM

Here are the relevant parts I've added to the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<permission
    android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

...

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.badbob.app.gmctestapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

I've added the following code to the onCreate of my main activity:

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice( this );
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest( this );
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId( this );
    if( regId.equals( "" ) ) {
        GCMRegistrar.register( this, GCM_SENDER_ID );
    }
    else {
        Log.v( LOG_TAG, "Already registered" );
    }
```

I've also created the GCMIntenetService class like so:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "GetAClue::GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super( GCM_SENDER_ID );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService constructor called" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError( Context arg0, String errorId ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onError called: " + errorId );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage( Context arg0, Intent intent ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onMessage called" );
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Message is: " + intent.getStringExtra( "message" ) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered( Context arg0, String registrationId ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onRegistered called" );
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Registration id is: " + registrationId );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered( Context arg0, String registrationId ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onUnregistered called" );
        Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Registration id is: " + registrationId );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GCM server is nothing but a XMPP server.

Have you seen this article: Impelementing GCM Server:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

Have a look at this

[Good XMPP Java Libraries for server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177514/good-xmpp-java-libraries-for-server-side)