# is it possible to create own XMPP server in Java

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, xmpp

By looking to this URL I know we can connect to XMPP server using this link
[Good XMPP Java Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177514/good-xmpp-java-libraries-for-server-side)

but I want to create my Own XMPP server, currently we have Openfire, tigase and many other Servers available. but is there any Libraries and tutorial are available for making an XMPP server from scratch?

I want to make a server that can handle all web, client application, Android and iOS requests (for Chat and other purpose).

Answer (score 0):

WebChat is perfect for this . You will have to download Openfire Server which is open source XMPP Server , then install Webchat over it , which will provide a web based interface to chat . You can use Android WebView to customize look and feel in an Android application

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rajendra but since I have many custom requirement I'm thinking to make my own XMPP server first that can work with all 3 clients. I have tried open fire already openfire isn't salable as Tigase but there is no tutorial to start with Tigase